# Catch dealloc (release) errors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have some issues in an app that I'm developing, where sometimes if I terminate while an animation is going on, it won't end up calling the release method in the internals of the animation api.

If I do [obj release] at the end just to be safe, well it will eventually cause an internal error to be thrown if the code does work correctly and release the object.

So, my question is, is there a way to ignore these errors calling release and just continue to the next line?

Comment: Seamus is right. By the way, run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on "Product" menu) and it will find a lot of routine memory management issues that can plague non-ARC code.

Comment: post some code, there's a safe way to end animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to safely ignore the errors.

Understanding object retention and release semantics is one of the most important parts of writing bug-free Objective-C code.  You'll save yourself a lot of these hassles if you enable automatic reference counting (ARC), but the fact is that you just can't be a serious Objective-C coder without understanding how this stuff works.

As far as the particular error, I suggest you provide some code snippets of your blocks and how you are canceling the animations, so that we can point out how to properly balance your release calls.

Comment: I understand completely, I was just hoping there was a way I could avoid having to dig into this open source package (cocos2d) that I'm using and finding out why it's not releasing its objects when interrupted.

Comment: Well, I was able to figure out the problem after about 2 hours of debugging the cocos2d code.  It was setting the action to a paused state and keeping a reference to it if it wasn't complete when I reset the scene.  I added a method to check for these and fix them.